# Who will publish a nonfic book of heavy BDSM?

Tags: publishing, independent-publishing

It's my autobio, but presented as porn instead of like a police report. Amazon sold a copy in 15 minutes, and after reading 85 pages, someone reported it as naughty.

A similar thing happened at smashwords. They published the 2007 edition, but the 2014 2nd edition with my recent experiences triggered a new review.

Is there anyone who will publish stuff with free-use [CNC torture](https://www.vice.com/en/article/m7vyk4/consensual-non-consent-meaning)? CNC is a lifestyle in which "two or more people agree to a sexual encounter that emulates rape." The ONLY difference between this "emulation" and real rape is that I don't call the cops. E.g, it involves strangers who slap me around and rough me up.

If not, how hard is it to sell it myself on my blog with paypal?

ty.